# using unique_ptr in qt member variable

Tags: c++, qt, smart-pointers

i want to use unique_ptr for a QMenu without making it as a child of the base widget so i have declared it like this

```
private:
std::unique_ptr<QMenu> m_pMenu;
```

and in constructor

```
std::unique_ptr<QMenu> m_pMenu ( new QMenu());
m_pMenu->setObjectName("JobContextMenu");
```

i also added 
CONFIG += c++11 in my  .pro file 
but when compiling  the unique_ptr is returning an error as
**Invalid application of 'sizeof' to an incomplete type 'QMenu'**

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate definition.
Also, you can do it in such way in C++ 11:

```
private:
std::unique_ptr<QMenu> m_pMenu = std::unique_ptr<QMenu>(new QMenu);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "duplicate defintion"?

Comment: you shouldn't mix `new` and `unique_ptr`. Use `std::make_unique` to construct the menu.

Comment: make_unique is C++ 14 feature, not C++ 11.

Comment: sure, it's c++14 (which the OP makes no mention of not being able to use), but this feature has been supported in all major compilers for some time. I down-voted your answer because it lacks substance and the advice is already dated, and will only become more so as time goes on and people look at this answer in the future.

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus, maybe in your usa everyone uses newest compilers, but in Russia and most of countries (as far as I know) there are very large limits on many works with compiler versions. So it is very desirable to take into account this fact. topic starter set his config to C++ 11 and I give advice for C++ 11.